# To select all fields from Zoho modules in CRM v2 apis

Tags: crm, zoho

In Zoho crm **getRecords** v1 api, to select all fields we have **selectColumns=All** option. What is its equivalent in zoho v2 apis ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question. that would help very much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

zoho crm v2 api by default selects all the fields. We don't have to include the attribute while making api call.